Windows 11 23H2: Disable mouse motion by graphics tablet without disabling HID-driver
I have a rather old USB graphics tablet (Aiptek HyperPen 12000U) connected to a desktop PC (no touchscreen or similar). The driver is the default one from Microsoft for HID devices, a suitable specialized driver is not available or not working. Original software package setup from Aiptek doesn't even start.
Windows itself doesn't position the mouse pointer correctly (because of different aspect ratios of screen and tablet, I guess) and doesn't transmit the pen pressure to applications.
There is an additional helper tool (called ATWTUSB) which allows to configure the tablet and would place the mouse pointer correctly.
Unfortunately Windows and the tool "fight" for the mouse pointer so that the pointer is jumping constantly between the positions set by the tool and by Windows.
Disabling the HID driver would disable the tool, too, so this isn't an option.
I tried to disable the Windows Ink Workspace with registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsInkWorkspace and a DWORD 32bit value AllowWindowsInkWorkspace set to 0. After restart, the mouse pointer is moved by Windows nevertheless.
What to do?
